# Virtual Hosts XAMPP [Linux Ubuntu] not working

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, vhosts

I tried to create a virtual host `magento.developers.com` in Ubuntu 12.04 using XAMPP.
First I have edited the `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and added the following lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@magento.developers.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento"
    ServerName magento.developers.com
    ErrorLog "logs/magento.developers.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/magento.developers.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have restarted XAMPP using the command `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart` and then I have edited
the hosts file and added:

```
127.0.0.1   magento.developers.com
```

Then I tried to access `magento.developers.com` using the browser and it's not accessing

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento
```

What I have to do to make it work and access `magento` folder instead of `htdocs` (the root)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The virtual hosts conf by defualt is disabled in httpd.conf, in order to allow virtual hosts
in XAMPP **under** Ubuntu you have to uncomment line `480` in `httpd.conf`:

**MAINSTEP**: Uncomment line `480` as below:

```
479. # Virtual hosts
480. Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The `httpd.conf` file is located under `/opt/lampp/etc`, to modify it just follow these steps:

1. run `sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`
2. apply **MAINSTEP**

Comment: @AmitGarg: does your htdocs work after you enable virtual hosts? My projects inside htdocs don't show up if I enable virtual hosts.. thats wierd :/

Comment: @GhazanfarMir My other projects on localhost was not working after creating vartualhost. So I have desabled virtual host.

Comment: @AmitGarg: Ok - I have figured out why my virtual hosts weren't working.. I had missed the entry for default htdocs directory which is `<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Once I put this entry for htdocs on top of other virtual hosts it started working.. I hope this would be of help

Comment: Do not forget to setup correctly your /etc/hosts file (equivalent to DNS entry). When adding vistual hosts, DNS table must be edited by you, then system do not do it automatically!

Comment: I was going nuts... you saved me. Tanks a lot. We are in 2020, and most of the time in developing applications is trying to figure out configuration, not programming solutions... is there a good apache2 tutorial that doesn't assume a lot of previous knowledge? Thank you again...

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Edit apache configuration

`sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`

and find below the line and uncomment (remove #) and save

`Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Step 2: Edit vhost configuration to Add Virtual Host

`sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

and add below code with your DocumentRoot (/opt/lampp/htdocs/example) and ServerName (URL)(example.local)

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin your@email.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/example"
    ServerName "example.local"
    ErrorLog "logs/example.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>`

Step 3: Edit host file to add your URL (example.local)

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

and add this line to the bottom with your URL (example.local) and save

`127.0.1.1  example.local`

Step 4: Restart server

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`

Answer (score 0):

**Create Vertual Host:-**

```
sudo vi /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```

and uncomment following line

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Now Create n number of host below commands:

`sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` (enter host entry).

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts                 (do host file entry)
```

then restart xampp

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```